# using fnDrawCallback inside fnInitComplete function in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hi i am using datatbles and am laoding the table using an async XHR call. I would liek to do [this](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6807/filtering-using-multiselect-dropdown-lists.-how-to-limit-conflicting-filter-options/p1) but due to the fact that I am calling the table using xhr my fnCreateSelect function is saying that the paramters are undefined due to the fact that there is no table data yet. is there a way to call the fnDrawCAllback inside of the fnInitComplete or vice versa?

any aother suggestions on how this could be done would be appreciated.

some code: this is my fnInitcomplete function I am also using fixed columns if that helps.

```
"fnInitComplete": function() {
                $("thead th").each( function ( i ) {
                    this.innerHTML += "<div class='DataTables_sort_wrapper'><span class='css_right ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></div><br/>"+fnCreateSelect( fleetT.fnGetColumnData(i) );
                    $("thead select").each( function (i) {
                        this.visibleIndex = i;
                    } );
                    $('select', this).change( function () {
                    var visIndex = typeof this.visibleIndex == 'undefined' ? 1 : this.visibleIndex;
                    fleetT.fnFilter( $(this).val(), visIndex);
                } );
            });
            new FixedColumns( fleetT, {
        "iLeftColumns": 2,
        "iLeftWidth": 220
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do works well when all data is already on the client, because it can get the distinct values to create a select. But if you do server side paging, the client has only a small portion of the dataset and for this reason you couldn't get the distinct values for the complete dataset, but only for the 10 / 25 rows you are managing at the moment. 
My suggestion is simply that you create the select server side ( by making normal DISTINCT queries to the db ) and then render them as normal.